# How do I search with php sessions using the native_session library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, search, native

I just found that i can't use PHPSESSIONS straight away in codeigniter so i've downloaded the Native_Sessions lib for Codeigniter.

I have a searchquery for searching postal codes in an database using an online postalcode database api. i store the postalcodes from the api in an session and would like to search with those postal codes in my factory table where i have a row Postcode for every factory.

So my factory table looks like this:

```
Factories
---------
Factoryid
Factoryname
Adress
Postcode
Country
...
...
...
```

My searchquery for the postcode looks like this:

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
        JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
        JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
        WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%')
```

**And this line for searching the postcode:**

```
        AND (Postcode LIKE '%". $_SESSION['postcodes'] ."%')
```

This does not work so I think I am doing it wrong. NOTE my session is called postcodes as shown above.

```
        GROUP BY `Categorie`, `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`";
        $query = $this->db->query($query);

        $result = $query->result_array();

        return $result;
```

code for setting the session. 
form:

javascript for the form: (using: http://www.d-centralize.nl/pro6pp/

```
    function send_data_to_server(output)
    {
        var post_code=$('.postcode').val();
        var url = 'http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/script.php?output='+output+'&post_code='+post_code;

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            success : function (data)
            {
            }
        });
    };
```

script.php where the data is sent to:

```
<?php 

echo '<pre>';
     session_start();

     $new_post_code=$_GET['post_code'];
        if($new_post_code!='' && $new_post_code!=0){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['searched_post_code']) || 
        empty($_SESSION['searched_post_code'])){ 
        $_SESSION['searched_post_code']=$new_post_code; 

        }elseif($_SESSION['searched_post_code']!=$new_post_code){ 

        $_SESSION['searched_post_code']=$new_post_code; 

        unset($_SESSION['postcodes']); 
        }
        }
     $output=$_GET['output'];
     $_SESSION['postcodes'][]=$output;
     echo $output;
     print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your session is being set, what does a var_dump of `$_SESSION` produce?

Comment: my session is set correctly as shown here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/script.php

Comment: `I just found that i can't use PHPSESSIONS straight away in codeigniter` **YOU CAN**

Comment: is it CAPSLOCK DAY AGAIN? how do i do that by the way?

Comment: do it native way. just use `session_start()` before outputting anything. means `public function foo(){ session_start(); // rest of the code }`

Comment: i did that in the script.php which i just posted. (the link to the session page) but do i have to set it more then once?

Comment: in every fricking function you will use `session`, you have to start it.

Comment: yeah. that does not work ^^ Message: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: .... or better, change to `yii` or `laravel` ;)

Comment: surprising. so `$_SESSION` never holds the data?

Comment: you are so helpful ._.

Comment: i removed the library and added session_start(); that does work. but still no results. i guess it's not right.

Comment: output the sql..... (the query) and see the actual query. problem is not session as i am seeing.

Comment: gives me an empty array because the results don't match. it has to do with the session actually.

Comment: the results don't match with what? your codes are so broken in parts that it is hard to follow.

Comment: i found what the problem is but i don't know how to fix that. the problem is that is searches for 'Postcode' LIKE '%' .Array => [0] => 9101 [1] 9102... etc. that way it is not working. i found that you can use in_array() in normal php. but how do I use something in sql.

Comment: The search results. don't match. that's what i mean.

Comment: post the code of how you are putting values in the _$_SESSION['postcode']_. (from where it is coming etc....)

Comment: 1. `var post_code=$('.postcode').val();` why using class? 2. `echo '<pre>';` why outputting before `session_start()`? 3. `$_SESSION['postcodes'][]=$output;` you are making the `$_SESSION['postcodes']` an array yourself.

Comment: i got that part from another user on SO. he told me this was the right way. but if you know better. it would be great.

Comment: that whole javascript code.

Comment: and also the part in script.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much error in your code. But i will address only the issue you are facing which is....

> i found what the problem is but i don't know how to fix that. the problem is that is searches for 'Postcode' LIKE '%' .Array => [0] => 9101 [1] 9102... etc. that way it is not working. i found that you can use in_array() in normal php. but how do I use something in sql.

as you have said in the comment above.

I am assuming `$_SESSION['postcode']` is an array with two elements 9101 and 9102.

<sub>script.php</sub>

```
$string = implode($_SESSION['postcode'], '|');
```

<sub>in your sql query file</sub>

```
AND (Postcode LIKE '%". $_SESSION['postcodes'] ."%')
```

Change it to,

```
AND (Postcode REGEXP '$string')
```

It'l give you the desired result.

Comment: it still does not work. it shows me the postal codes 9101|9102|9132 etc etc but still no searchresults.

Comment: run the actual query with all the values in phpmydmin and see if it returns any result.

Comment: Error Number: 1139

Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

Comment: because your `$_SESSION['postcode']` is empty! use some basic debugging. 1st, make sure `$_SESSION['postcode']` is **NOT** empty. 2nd, implode `$_SESSION['postcode']` into '|' seperated string. 3rd echo the query. 4th, run the query. If no result, then 5th, run the ecohed query (in step 3) in phpmyadmin. If there is no result then too, it means no results are there!

Comment: my session is NOT EMPTY. it works when i use implode('9101') but when i use more than 1 postal code it gives 0 searchresults. i think because it is regognized as 1 big word. ('9101|9102|9103|etc') so that's the problem.

Comment: who told you to put `()` around those numbers?

Comment: i made an array for testing. like $test = implode('9101|9102|9103|9132'); that's why i have the () around them. So don't be rude ._.

Comment: `$test = implode('9101|9102|9103|9132');` not trying to be rude here but this doesn't make any sense and should throw an error cz of incorrect syntax.

Comment: sorry i mean array instead of implode.

Comment: anyway this is the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''9131|9293|9290|9294|9291|9295')

Comment: _" i think because it is regognized as 1 big word. ('9101|9102|9103|etc') so that's the problem." **No, it doesn't sees as big word.** it is same as mulitple `LIKE` and `OR` COMBINATION statement.

Comment: hm. but why does 1 postalcode like 9101 work but multiple like 9101|9102|9103 don't

Comment: ok. post the **WHOLE** query. without any break. The **exact** one that you are running. No modifications.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29923/discussion-between-kees-sonnema-and-itachi)